# How do I change the default font for Chinese in OneNote?

Tags: fonts, microsoft-onenote, i18n

I know it is possible to change the default font for all languages in OneNote, but is it possible to change the default font for Chinese, or is it a systemwide setting? It currently defaults to "Microsoft YaHei" when I switch to the Chinese keyboard and type anything. I am using the latest version of OneNote.